# Proving a particular piecewise function is as odd function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 \quad &-\pi \lt\ x \lt 0 \\ 1 \quad &0\lt x\lt \pi \end{cases}
\tag1$

How would you prove that this is an odd function?

Comment: Is $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be getting this wrong, but there doesn't seem to be much to prove. A function is odd if $f(x)=-f(-x)$. This is obviously the case since for all $0<x<\pi$ you have $f(x)=1=-(-1)=-f(-x)$ and vice versa for negative x.

Comment: I see! I think I get it now, thank you for your help